# Is there any way to write the function without explicitly using defaultProps in react function component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a component like

```
import React, { ReactNode } from "react";

const defaultContainerProps = {
  heading: <h1>Default Heading</h1>,
};

function App({
  children,
  heading,
}: {
  children: ReactNode;
} & typeof defaultContainerProps) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{heading}</h1>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
}

App.defaultProps = defaultContainerProps;

export default App;
```

it works absolutely fine, but in es6 default props can be directly given in the function parameters, so I updated my function like this

```
const defaultContainerProps = {
  heading: <h1>Default Heading</h1>,
};

function App({
  children,
  heading = defaultContainerProps.heading,
}: {
  children: ReactNode;
} & typeof defaultContainerProps) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{heading}</h1>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
}
```

but it is expecting me to give the heading prop when I use this component
**error : Property 'heading' is missing in type '{ children: string; }' but required in type '{ heading: JSX.Element; }'.**

main file which use that component

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App>Foo</App> // Property 'heading' is missing in type '{ children: string; }' but required in type '{ heading: JSX.Element; }'.
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the default value, the value in the method argument needs to be null, and the type of the parameter doesn't allow for nulls. To make it work use `Partial` utility type (it makes everything nullable)

```
function App({ children,
 heading = defaultContainerProps.heading,}: {
 children: ReactNode;} & Partial<typeof defaultContainerProps>)
```